# Evaluate an expression, users can enter as many numbers and operators as they want

Tags: c

This is the Programming Project 7.12 of the C Programming - A Modern Approach. The program is expected to evaluate an expression (for example 1+2.5*3) and return its result (10.5 in this case, note that the expression is evaluated from left to right, and no operator takes precedence over any other operator).

This is what I've tried (the expression is 1 + 2.5 *3, for example): store 1 in a, + in ch, and 2.5 in b. Then let result = a, compute the "new" result by either adding, subtracting, dividing or multiplying with b. Then continue reading the expression, storing * in ch, and 3 in b. Run the while loop again until the scanf detects a new-line character. I wonder what is wrong with my method, or my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    float a, b, result;
    char ch;
    printf("Enter an expression: ");
    scanf("%f%c%f", &a, &ch, &b);
    result = a;
    while (ch != '\n') {
        if (ch == '+')
            result += b;
        else if (ch == '-')
            result -= b;
        else if (ch == '*')
            result *= b;
        else if (ch == '/') {
            result /= b; }
        scanf("%c", &ch);
        scanf("%f", &b);
    }
    printf("Value of expression: %.2f", result);
    return 0;
}
```

It doesn't return anything :(

Comment: The code you have will *not* parse your stated expression `1 + 2.5 *3` as you desire. Those spaces will muck up your `scanf` from the get-go because `%c` does not automatically skip whitespace. Checking the actual result of `scanf` for the number of arguments correctly parsed is a good idea.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yeah I know the scanf doesnt skip white spaces. When I enter an expression I don't put in any white space between the numbers and the operators. Still, the program doesnt return anything, even the sentence inside the printf.

Comment: "When I enter an expression I don't put in any white space between the numbers and the operators" --> then why post "1 + 2.5 *3" instead of "1+2.5*3\n"?  Post true input used.  Also append `"\n"` to `printf()` format.

Comment: @chux I apologize for causing confusion. I'll do it next time

Comment: Use `fgets` and parse the string. This will save you all the `scanf` related problems.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thank you for your response. However I am following the C Programming - A Modern Approach book, and it hasn't mentioned the `fgets` function so far (I'm currently at the end of Chapter 7). The book must have assumed that `scanf` is enough for this programming project. I will use `fgets` as soon as it comes up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even after you press enter after putting complete expression.

```
scanf("%c", &ch);
scanf("%f", &b);
```

Will still wait to input float because of order of `scanf`.

Just break immediately once you press enter as below.

```
while (ch != '\n') {
    if (ch == '+')
        result += b;
    else if (ch == '-')
        result -= b;
    else if (ch == '*')
        result *= b;
    else if (ch == '/') {
        result /= b; }
    scanf("%c", &ch);
    if (ch == '\n') break;
    scanf("%f", &b);
}
```

---

> I would suggest you to use `fgets` to read the complete expression at
>   once and process the expression afterwards also your current code is very naive wouldn't even work for complex expression which includes `(`, `)` etc, you may want to use LIFO data structure by processing the read expression in reverse order.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However I am following the C Programming - A Modern Approach book, and it hasn't mentioned the fgets function so far (I'm currently at the end of Chapter 7).